# Liquid - switch statement with a variable

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, shopify, liquid

I have the following situation:

```
<label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: 
        {% capture color %} {{ value | handle }} {% endcapture %}

      {% assign handle = color %}
        {% case handle %}
          {% when 'red' %}
             red;
          {% when 'navy' %}
             navy;
          {% else %}
             #f00;
        {% endcase %}

background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | file_url }})">
```

When I do {{color}} it prints the right color, but when I try to use it in a comparison statement it fails, returns blank (or rather the default which is `#f00`. Same with the IF statement.

If I define the

```
{% assign handle = 'red' %}
```

then it works fine.

Comment: What does `{{ handle }}` return when `{% assign handle = color %}` is used?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `{{ value | handleize }}` ? As far as I'm aware "handle" is not the right operator.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I found this worked for me...

Try using **capture** instead of the **assign**, like this:

```
{% capture handle}{{ color }}{% endcapture %}
```

Then proceed with your case statement as before:

```
{% case handle %}...
```